# jspdf header needs to repeat multiple pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, jspdf

I am implimenting jspdf code with jquery script and jspdf.debug.js file.  I have a very large html table (angular ng-repeat) and it is repeating many pages.  jspdf is smart enough to make the header of the table repeat nicely, but I also have some invoice information at the top which doesn't repeat every page, only first one.  Any suggestions?  I'm assuming I have to change the jquery somewhere, but no clue how.

UPDATE:  HERE IS MY HTML CODE SO FAR:

```
        <div id="content" class="modal-body" modal-transclude>
           <header style="display:none;"> <img width="120" height="80" src="../../../../Images/Logo.png"/> </header>

                <div id="bypassme">
                    <button id="bypassme" onclick="Javascript:demoFromHTML();">Create PDF now 2</button>
                    <table class="pdfTable">
                        <tr>
                            <td width="70%">
                                <table id="content32" class="pdfTable">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><img style="width:120px; height:80px;" src="../../../../Images/ Logo.png" /></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td> Phone # 123-456-789 Fax # 123-456-789</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                            <td width="30%">
                                <table class="pdfTable">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="font-size:24px"> Purchase Order</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <table class="pdfTableWithBorder">
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th>
                                                        Date
                                                    </th>
                                                    <th>P.O. No. </th>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;">
                                                        {{date | date:'MM/dd/yy'}}
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        {{Number}}
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>

                    <table class="pdfTable">
                        <tr>
                            <td width="50%">
                                <table class="pdfTableWithBorder">
                                    <tr><th>Vendor</th> </tr>
                                    <tr height="100"><td>vendor name</td></tr>
                                </table>
                            </td>

                            <td width="50%">
                                <table class="pdfTableWithBorder">
                                    <tr><th>Ship To</th> </tr>
                                    <tr height="100">
                                        <td>
                                            company
                                            <br />address
                                            <br />city
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <table class="pdfTableWithBorder">
                        <tr>
                            <td width="40%" style="border: 1px solid black;">Container #</td>
                            <td width="40%" style="border: 1px solid black;">Bill </td>
                            <td width="10%" style="border: 1px solid black;">{{date | date:'MM/dd/yy'}}</td>
                            <td width="10%" style="border: 1px solid black;">info</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <br />

                </div>

            <table id="content2" class="pdfTable" style="font-size: 12px">
                <tr>
                    <th align="left">Qty</th>
                    <th align="left">Item</th>
                    <th align="center">Description</th>
                    <th align="center">Rate</th>
                    <th align="center">Amount</th>
                </tr>
                <tr ng-repeat="item in items" ng-class-odd="'odd'" ng-class-even="'even'">
                    <td align="left">{{item.qty}}</td>
                    <td align="left">{{item.Code}}</td>
                    <td align="center">{{item.Desc}}</td>
                    <td align="center">{{item.price}}</td>
                    <td align="center">{{item.qty * item.price}}</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>


</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

by adding a `header` tag in the html the `jsPDF` engine is reading this tag and add it to the top of every page.

```js
function demoFromHTML() {
    var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter');
    // source can be HTML-formatted string, or a reference
    // to an actual DOM element from which the text will be scraped.
    source = document.querySelector('#customers');

    // we support special element handlers. Register them with jQuery-style 
    // ID selector for either ID or node name. ("#iAmID", "div", "span" etc.)
    // There is no support for any other type of selectors 
    // (class, of compound) at this time.
    specialElementHandlers = {
        // element with id of "bypass" - jQuery style selector
        '#bypassme': function (element, renderer) {
            // true = "handled elsewhere, bypass text extraction"
            return true
        }
    };
    margins = {
        top: 80,
        bottom: 60,
        left: 40,
        width: 522
    };
    // all coords and widths are in jsPDF instance's declared units
    // 'inches' in this case
    pdf.fromHTML(
    source, // HTML string or DOM elem ref.
    margins.left, // x coord
    margins.top, { // y coord
        'width': margins.width, // max width of content on PDF
        'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
    },

    function (dispose) {
        // dispose: object with X, Y of the last line add to the PDF 
        //          this allow the insertion of new lines after html
        pdf.save('Test.pdf');
    }, margins);
}
```

```html
<script src="http://mrrio.github.io/jsPDF/dist/jspdf.debug.js"></script>
<button onclick="javascript:demoFromHTML();">PDF</button>
<div id="customers">
    <header>Awsome Header!!!</header>
    <table id="tab_customers" class="table table-striped">
        <colgroup>
            <col width="20%">
                <col width="20%">
                    <col width="20%">
                        <col width="20%">
        </colgroup>
        <thead>
          <tbody>
           <tr>
                <td>United States</td>
                <td>317,746,000</td>
                <td>March 24, 2014</td>
                <td>4.44</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Indonesia</td>
                <td>249,866,000</td>
                <td>July 1, 2013</td>
                <td>3.49</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Brazil</td>
                <td>201,032,714</td>
                <td>July 1, 2013</td>
                <td>2.81</td>
            </tr>
           <tr>
                <td>United States</td>
                <td>317,746,000</td>
                <td>March 24, 2014</td>
                <td>4.44</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Indonesia</td>
                <td>249,866,000</td>
                <td>July 1, 2013</td>
                <td>3.49</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Brazil</td>
                <td>201,032,714</td>
                <td>July 1, 2013</td>
                <td>2.81</td>
            </tr>
           <tr>
                <td>United States</td>
                <td>317,746,000</td>
                <td>March 24, 2014</td>
                <td>4.44</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Indonesia</td>
                <td>249,866,000</td>
                <td>July 1, 2013</td>
                <td>3.49</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Brazil</td>
                <td>201,032,714</td>
                <td>July 1, 2013</td>
                <td>2.81</td>
            </tr>
           <tr>
                <td>United States</td>
                <td>317,746,000</td>
                <td>March 24, 2014</td>
                <td>4.44</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Indonesia</td>
                <td>249,866,000</td>
                <td>July 1, 2013</td>
                <td>3.49</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Brazil</td>
                <td>201,032,714</td>
                <td>July 1, 2013</td>
                <td>2.81</td>
            </tr>
           <tr>
                <td>United States</td>
                <td>317,746,000</td>
                <td>March 24, 2014</td>
                <td>4.44</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Indonesia</td>
                <td>249,866,000</td>
                <td>July 1, 2013</td>
                <td>3.49</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Brazil</td>
                <td>201,032,714</td>
                <td>July 1, 2013</td>
                <td>2.81</td>
            </tr>
           <tr>
                <td>United States</td>
                <td>317,746,000</td>
                <td>March 24, 2014</td>
                <td>4.44</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Indonesia</td>
                <td>249,866,000</td>
                <td>July 1, 2013</td>
                <td>3.49</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Brazil</td>
                <td>201,032,714</td>
                <td>July 1, 2013</td>
                <td>2.81</td>
            </tr>
           <tr>
                <td>United States</td>
                <td>317,746,000</td>
                <td>March 24, 2014</td>
                <td>4.44</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Indonesia</td>
                <td>249,866,000</td>
                <td>July 1, 2013</td>
                <td>3.49</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Brazil</td>
                <td>201,032,714</td>
                <td>July 1, 2013</td>
                <td>2.81</td>
            </tr>
           <tr>
                <td>United States</td>
                <td>317,746,000</td>
                <td>March 24, 2014</td>
                <td>4.44</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Indonesia</td>
                <td>249,866,000</td>
                <td>July 1, 2013</td>
                <td>3.49</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Brazil</td>
                <td>201,032,714</td>
                <td>July 1, 2013</td>
                <td>2.81</td>
            </tr>
           <tr>
                <td>United States</td>
                <td>317,746,000</td>
                <td>March 24, 2014</td>
                <td>4.44</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Indonesia</td>
                <td>249,866,000</td>
                <td>July 1, 2013</td>
                <td>3.49</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Brazil</td>
                <td>201,032,714</td>
                <td>July 1, 2013</td>
                <td>2.81</td>
            </tr>
           <tr>
                <td>United States</td>
                <td>317,746,000</td>
                <td>March 24, 2014</td>
                <td>4.44</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Indonesia</td>
                <td>249,866,000</td>
                <td>July 1, 2013</td>
                <td>3.49</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Brazil</td>
                <td>201,032,714</td>
                <td>July 1, 2013</td>
                <td>2.81</td>
            </tr>
           <tr>
                <td>United States</td>
                <td>317,746,000</td>
                <td>March 24, 2014</td>
                <td>4.44</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Indonesia</td>
                <td>249,866,000</td>
                <td>July 1, 2013</td>
                <td>3.49</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Brazil</td>
                <td>201,032,714</td>
                <td>July 1, 2013</td>
                <td>2.81</td>
            </tr>           <tr>
                <td>United States</td>
                <td>317,746,000</td>
                <td>March 24, 2014</td>
                <td>4.44</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Indonesia</td>
                <td>249,866,000</td>
                <td>July 1, 2013</td>
                <td>3.49</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Brazil</td>
                <td>201,032,714</td>
                <td>July 1, 2013</td>
                <td>2.81</td>
            </tr>
           <tr>
                <td>United States</td>
                <td>317,746,000</td>
                <td>March 24, 2014</td>
                <td>4.44</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Indonesia</td>
                <td>249,866,000</td>
                <td>July 1, 2013</td>
                <td>3.49</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Brazil</td>
                <td>201,032,714</td>
                <td>July 1, 2013</td>
                <td>2.81</td>
            </tr>
           <tr>
                <td>United States</td>
                <td>317,746,000</td>
                <td>March 24, 2014</td>
                <td>4.44</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Indonesia</td>
                <td>249,866,000</td>
                <td>July 1, 2013</td>
                <td>3.49</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Brazil</td>
                <td>201,032,714</td>
                <td>July 1, 2013</td>
                <td>2.81</td>
            </tr>
           <tr>
                <td>United States</td>
                <td>317,746,000</td>
                <td>March 24, 2014</td>
                <td>4.44</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Indonesia</td>
                <td>249,866,000</td>
                <td>July 1, 2013</td>
                <td>3.49</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Brazil</td>
                <td>201,032,714</td>
                <td>July 1, 2013</td>
                <td>2.81</td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

check out `<header>Awsome Header!!!</header>`

Comment: wow. thanks.  that may be what i need, but I also need to know why when I embed images in tables, i lose them.  in general, i would like to add tables to my header (for alignment and formatting purposes but jspdf makes it hard.  how else would i right align and left align on same row with jspdf?)

Comment: you can try add image in the header. about the image, did you try to convert the image to `base65`?

Comment: what about alignment issues.  is there a workaround besides for table ?

Comment: example will be nice :)

Comment: I updated the question with the code.  (note. I already added the header tag and began getting it to work)

Comment: the image isn't in base64 you are doing it on the fly?

Comment: yes.  the image works the way i have it now.  i don't know what you mean by base64.  the image isn't really my problem now.  i need to get some text to display right aligned same row as the image.  i can't put image in a table and anyways jspdf doesn't let me customize my tables easily.  so is there a way to right align a span or div next to that image in the header tag?

Comment: do you have an idea?

Comment: if you try to set a logo or somethink in the header you can just add an image that his width is the width of the pdf page

Comment: the image is just in the left corner.  i want to have text in a table in the right corner even with the image.

Comment: do you know how to impliment this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36347346/jquery-jspdf-add-text-to-header-with-text-method

Comment: any advice?  The header tag isn't so helpful in the end since it doesn't support normal formation of tables and alignment.

Comment: What if you need to add a header and footer that's not visible on the html page?