# Add text to header with .text method

Tags: javascript, jquery, jspdf

Can someone tell me how to get text to repeat like header does in jspdf.  if I add text  like this (jspdf.text(x,y,'test') it's only going on first page!

note:  I already have a header on this doc but that's done in the html with the `<header>` tag.   I want to append to that sort of.  I have to add the text this way as a work around for alignment issues jspdf has.

```
var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter');
pdf.rect(430, 20, 125, 50);
pdf.text('Order', 430, 35);
pdf.autoTableHtmlToJson
source = $('#content')[0]; //table Id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up cracking the entire jspdf.debug.js code and adding tons of if statements to it in order to solve my issues with how it renders tables.  a few examples below:

--the cell height was huge for the headers

```
   if (printHeaders) {
//changed by me on 4/5/16 to calculate lineheight manually
var lineHeight = 20;//this.calculateLineHeight(headerNames, columnWidths, headerPrompts.length?headerPrompts:headerNames);
```

I had a problem that once I was adding tables to my header, the doc was repeating the last header from the header for my MAIN DATA table that had 100 records or more (so it repeated multiple pages and pages 2+ had wrong header)

```
// Store the table header config  
        //changed by me
        this.setTableHeaderRow(tableHeaderConfigs);
        if (tableHeaderConfigsMain != undefined) {
            if (tableHeaderConfigsMain.length > 0) {
                this.setTableHeaderRowMain(tableHeaderConfigsMain);
            }
        }
```

--I added this to the for loop that constructs the header row (my main table had 5 columns)

```
        if (headerNames.length == 5) {
            tableHeaderConfigsMain.push([x, y, columnWidths[header], lineHeight, String(headerPrompts.length ? headerPrompts[i] : header)]);
}
```

--added this to the print header row function

```
if (this.tableHeaderRowMain != undefined && new_page) {
    if (this.tableHeaderRowMain.length > 0) {
        this.tableHeaderRow = this.tableHeaderRowMain;
    }
}
```

--in the tabletojson function i changed this to manually set up my tables

```
if(table.id=='rightAlignTable'){
                headers[i] = {
                    name : cell.textContent.toLowerCase().replace(/\s+/g, ''),
                    prompt: 'Date', //cell.textContent.replace(/\r?\n/g, ''),
                    width : 100 //(cell.clientWidth / table_with) * renderer.pdf.internal.pageSize.width

                };
                headers[1] = {
                    name : cell.textContent.toLowerCase().replace(/\s+/g, ''),
                    prompt: 'PO #',//cell.textContent.replace(/\r?\n/g, ''),
                    width : 100 //(cell.clientWidth / table_with) * renderer.pdf.internal.pageSize.width
                };
            }
```

--i also manually changed tables here in the ****TABLE RENDERING**** section:

```
            if (cn.id === "rightAlignTable") {
                x = 425;
                y = 25;
            }
```